# How to read a WebClient response after posting data? WebClient.UploadData Method (String, String, Byte[])

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

My Code here.

```
string uriString = "http://www.Testcom";
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
string postData = "data";
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Console.WriteLine(myWebClient.Headers.ToString());
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);        
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData(new 
Uri(uriString),"POST",byteArray);
```

Now I call UploadData and get method created in my API project something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("doc2pdf")]
public HttpResponseMessage doc2pdf(byte[] fileContent)
{
    string pdfContent = string.Empty;
    //if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(docContent))
    //{
    //    var resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,"Document content is empty.");
    //    return resp;
    //}
    if(fileContent != null || fileContent.Length > 0)
    {
        ..logic here
    }
}
```

The problem is always fileContent get {byte[0]}.
[image]

Now, how do I read the HTTP output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferable way to send data in WebApi is a using JSON. But if you want to use form encoded data, you should:

1. Hint WebAPI to use request body to read parameter and use simple type
   `public HttpResponseMessage doc2pdf([FromBody]string fileContent)`
2. Send the data with a leading "=" sign.

So, client code

```
string uriString = "http://www.Testcom";

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
string postData = "=data";
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Console.WriteLine(myWebClient.Headers.ToString());
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData(new Uri(uriString), "POST", byteArray);
```

Server side code

```
public HttpResponseMessage doc2pdf([FromBody]string fileContent)
{
    //..logic here
}
```